# Excel VBA - Export a copy of current workbook

Tags: vba, excel

**The Task**

I am working on a chart generator from a data sheet. As part of my spec, I need to be able to extract this chart into its separate workbook.

**My Functions**

This is the function I currently have:

```
Sub EWbtn()
'''Extract Worksheet Button Function

Dim OriginalWB As Workbook, NewCRCWB As Workbook

Set OriginalWB = ThisWorkbook
Set NewCRCWB = Workbooks.Add

OriginalWB.Sheets("Generator").Copy Before:=NewCRCWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
OriginalWB.Sheets("Module Part Number Tracker").Copy Before:=NewCRCWB.Sheets("Generator")
OriginalWB.Sheets("CRC").Copy Before:=NewCRCWB.Sheets("Module Part Number Tracker")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
NewCRCWB.Worksheets("Generator").Visible = False
NewCRCWB.Worksheets("Module Part Number Tracker").Visible = False
NewCRCWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I copy through the 2 sheets from which the data for the chart is used, and make them hidden in the new workbook. The CRC sheet has quite a few macros that are run on the chart and can also be called via buttons on the chart. For example this function is for a button which hides 5 columns of data on the chart:

```
Public Function SHGSbtn()
'''Show Hides Gateway Stages Function

Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
Set wsCRC = Worksheets("CRC")

If wsCRC.Buttons("SHGateway").Caption = "Hide Gateway Stages" Then

    Range(Cells(9, 9), Cells(9, 13)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    wsCRC.Buttons("SHGateway").Caption = "Show Gateway Stages"

ElseIf wsCRC.Buttons("SHGateway").Caption = "Show Gateway Stages" Then

    Range(Cells(9, 9), Cells(9, 13)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
wsCRC.Buttons("SHGateway").Caption = "Hide Gateway Stages"

End If

End Function
```

**My Issue**

The workbook copies over with no errors, however when i try and use one of the buttons, it uses the code in the original workbook, even if its closed it will open up the original workbook. Anyone know why this is and how do I get around it?

Comment: please right click on button and goto Assign macro and check Macro Name. i think button is referencing to original file macro. please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392447/copy-a-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook-and-have-a-button-point-to-the-macro-in-the-n

Comment: why not save a copy of the original workbook and then delete what you don't need?